# Cropperjs Crop Circle

Tags: angular, typescript, cropperjs

How set the [cropperjs](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs) crop area to a circle.
I use angular/typescript and the ngx-img module.

This is my component.html code:

```
 <ngx-img (onSelect)="imgEditorOnSelect($event)"
          (onReset)="imgEditorOnReset()"
          [config]="img_editor_config">
 </ngx-img>
```

And my component.ts code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    /**
     * configuracion para el cropperjs
     * https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/
     */
    this.img_editor_config = {
        crop: [{ ratio: 2 / 3, viewMode: 3 }]
    }
}
```

Comment: CropperJS does not support circular crop boxes, but maybe this will help: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/issues/545

Comment: thanks I do not need anything else :D